# Perl - Error : Cant locate file in @INC

Tags: perl, module, user-defined

As I am Novice to Perl, I would be happy if you are able to solve my problem.

I created a Module named "Messages.pm" and it resides in the path "E:\Venkadachalam\Perl_samples\Modules\Messages.pm"

Also I included this module in another Perl file named "Main.pl" as show below

```
use Modules::Messages;
```

and invoked the subroutine defined in the Messaged.pm in the Main.pl

In the Command Window, I tried executing the above perl program as

```
perl -I E:\Venkadachalam\Perl_samples\Modules\Messages.pm Main.pl
```

Here it gives an error message as shown below:

```
"Can't locate Modules/Messages.pm in @INC (@INC contains: E:/Venkadachalam/Perl_s
ample/Modules C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at Main.pl line 1
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Main.pl line 1"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your command says `Perl_samples` but the error says `Perl_sample`. Which is it?

Comment: Its Perl_sample on both the places.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying `use Modules::Messages;` and pointing the lib to `E:/Venkadachalam/Perl_sample/Modules`. So it is expecting lib to be `E:/Venkadachalam/Perl_sample/Modules/Modules/Messages.pm`.

Change it to `E:/Venkadachalam/Perl_sample`

[Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)

Comment: E:\Venkadachalam\Perl_sample\Modules> perl -I E:\Venkadachalam\Perl_sample Main.p
l
Modules/Messages.pm did not return a true value at Main.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Main.pl line 1.

Comment: Above is the Error Coming to me.

Comment: That's a different question then. Briefly, a valid module needs to have `1;` at the end. Actually, all of this is documented, and eminently googlable.